# Connect to MySQL Web Database and list results with Pictures Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, while-loop

This is more a quick question on the capabilities of Android.

I want to develop an app on android, and I am going to purchase an android device when doing so.

I know there are methods out there and tutorials to connect to a MySQL database. What I want to do is connect to the database through the app (securely), run a MySQL query (PHP file) and then get the results. This is all possible, but when it returns, is it just as simple as doing a while/for loop and then make a result, and put some other data with it? For example a picture etc?

I am just thinking it may be more complicated.

For example I have the MONSTERS table:

```
id    name    colour     picture
1     bob     red        bobsred.png
2     greg    green      gregsgreen.png
```

...EXAMPLE...

And I want the results to come up like this:

```
BOB   (picture)
GREG  (picture)
```

Each being buttons that then go to a different page/form or something like that.

Let me reiterate I am not looking for code, but rather someone to confirm its possible from some Android Developers!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's entirely possible. And there are probably a number of ways of doing it. There will be abundant code samples available for your googling pleasure.

Pass your values to PHP via a GET. Return as JSON or XML or whatever makes you happy. Loop through and build your display table.

Comment: Thank you dear sir! Needed 100% confirmation from a non static source :D ... Yea I thought as much .Thanks again - Will accept your answer when I can :)

Comment: Here's and example that uses java: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/http/android-how-to-send-http-get-request-to-servlet-using-apache-http-client/